# Saving and Image from RTSP Stream (VB6)

Tags: vb6, rtsp

I am going to start off this question with; Yes.  I **have** to use Visual Basic 6.0 to program this.  It's out of my control which programming language is being used, and the one I have been told to use is VB6.

I am trying to create a program that can fetch the data from a RTSP Stream and save a single shot of the video feed to a bmp file.  I have been looking on Google, and on Overflow, but I haven't been able to find a solution on how to go about accomplishing this.

One of the things I am worried about is compatibility issues.  For example, one of my searches early on led me to EmguCV, but I can't get that working for VB6, and honestly I never really expected to get it working.

So are there any good libraries, or built in features for VB6 that can help me accomplish what I am trying to do?  I am kind of just hitting my head against a brick wall here.

Comment: EmguCV is a .NET library. So you could write a C# or VB.NET wrapper which internally uses EmguCV but also provides a COM-visible set of methods which VB6 would be able to access.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Windows Media Control](http://planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=67608&lngWId=1) for the heavy lifting (streaming, video decoding, etc).

Just have to figure out how to pause first frame of the stream and capture it.

Comment: So I actually found this yesterday, long after posting this question.  However when I put in the RTSP link I am told to enter a Network Password.  I've tried everything, from the LAN admin password, to the password setup for the RTSP origin, but I can't connect to the feed.

Comment: @Skitzafreak that sounds like a different problem, consider posting a new question for it.